# Do RestKit completion blocks run on the main UI thread?

Tags: ios, multithreading, restkit

My code tells me it is via `[NSThread currentThread] isMainThread]` and the fact that I can show a `UIAlertView` as well. This seems unexpected because my understanding is that requests are dispatched asynchronously.

I'd throw in some relevant code, but it's nothing special. I `POST` an object via the `RKObjectManager` and the `success` and `failure` completion blocks execute on the main UI thread (even though I am definitely doing stuff in the background after the request completes).

I'm confused.

What's going on?

Comment: requests a are asynchronously but the completion block should return to main thread.

Comment: that seems logical. Why not make it an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why you want requests are dispatched asynchronously because you don't want UI Thread (which is main thread) blocked by the request. because when it blocked , your App wont react user's action , that's a bad user experience.

Then after the request is done, you want to let the user know it, so the dispatched thread must return to main thread. in your situation, that's the completion block. then you can do things like show alert on the main thread.

I hope this is the answer you want.

Comment: Before I accept I'm going to confirm this is what is happening in the RestKit code. I'll return to this answer in a couple days. Thanks!

Comment: It's actually AFNetworking code which returns to the main thread after the network activity is complete and that's where the success block is called from.

Answer (score 7):

`RKObjectManager` behind the scenes creates and posts an `RKObjectRequestOperation` (which is essentially representation of your POST request) into `NSOperationQueue` to perform all the networking and mapping stuff asynchronously in the background thread.

When request is finished and response processed - default behavior is to run `success` or `failure` callbacks on the main thread. This is nice quick setup that helps you to build an app very fast and easy (and not worry about updating UI on the right thread).

You can easily change that behavior, `RKObjectRequestOperation` has 2 properties, `successCallbackQueue` and `failureCallbackQueue`, you can set them to be another background thread, and then when you need to change something on the UI side, just wrap that change into a block and post to main queue:

```
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
    }];
```

Comment: This makes sense to me, but I don't see it in the documentation, that the success or failure callbacks are on the main thread by default.